# Running caret model outside of R?

Tags: c, r, machine-learning, embed, r-caret

Suppose that I have created a machine learning model through R's [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/) package. Now how can I take that model out of R and embed it in my own application to process out-of-sample data?

Preferably something that generates C code for any POSIX-compliant system (and the generated code must *not* under the terms of any viral open-source licenses, or require a run-time that does). However C++ code or the like is acceptable.

To illustrate in code, suppose I've ran this code in R:

```
modFit <- train(preProcess="pca",method="rf", trControl=trainControl(method="cv"), ...)
```

Now I am looking for something to run the model, like so:

```
predictionResult <- predict(modFit,moreData)
```

But run it inside my application. It's acceptable to serialize `modFit` out into a file and have it translated into plain C or have something embeddable which reads that serialized model and runs it.

In other words, I'm looking to somehow embed R's `predict` function inside my application but just for running the model that I've already created. However I don't want to embed R nor make my app GPL.

Comment: It depends on which model you are fitting.  You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Have you considered using shiny yet?

Comment: As Andrie says, it is very model specific. I fooled around with starting an R package for doing this and it wasn't that hard for neural nets, MARS/FDA and linear models. However, it gets hairy after that. Some packages ([inTrees](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inTrees/index.html)) would make it easier in some cases. There is also [PMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) and their [R package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=pmml).